# What is the difference between an Emir and a Sultan?

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference between an Emir and a Sultan? Are they both Sheik?

For instance, OALD defines:

> Emir: the title given to some Muslim rulers
>
> Emirate: an area of land that is ruled over by an emir
>
> Sultan: the title given to Muslim rulers in some countries
>
> Sultanate: an area of land that is ruled over by a sultan

While OAAD defines (there is no entry for Sheik on OALD, why?):

> Sheik:
>   1 an Arab prince or leader; the head of an Arab family, town,
>   etc. / 2 a leader in a Muslim community or organization

Could we say that "Emperor":"King"="Emir":"Sultan"?

Comment: Well, I can copy out the OED’s entries for all three, which are much better than what you have given here, but these are all from the 1989 OED2: they haven’t been updated for the OED3 yet. Would that be of any help?

Comment: I don't think this is really about English. Sheik, emir and sultan are all borrowed words which are used in an adopted context.

Comment: @simchona - but I found this five words in English dictionary: http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sheikh http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sultanate http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sultan http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/Emirate http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/emir

Comment: @LewisCarroll All of the words are borrowed, and their definition depends on the Muslim or Arabic concepts of nobility--not English.

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to history.se?

Comment: @T.E.D. I've never really spent time there, have you? I couldn't say whether the migration would work

Comment: @simchona - It's my main SE hangout now. My guess is that you'd get one or two good answers there, but I could be wrong. It is in beta right now.

Comment: @T.E.D. You better than I would then. Maybe bring it up over there in chat if you could?

Comment: @simchona No, their definitions ***in English*** do not depend on their origins.  This is known as an etymological fallacy.

Comment: Suggest migrating to historySE.

Comment: If we can't reach agreement on http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63039/8019, there's unlikely to be a consensus on this one.

Comment: @simchona - I asked in chat ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine ), and they said they'd be happy to take it. I don't know the procedure from here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entries from the *OED* provided below.

Note carefully the years that these words entered English:

- For example, ***emirate*** is extremely recent.
- You missed the eldest of terms, ***caliph***, such as the exceedingly famous [*Caliphate of Córdova*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliphate_of_C%F3rdoba), which ruled Iberia and northern Africa between 929–1031.
- There is apparently no attested word *∗sheik(h)dom*.

These are all taken from the online *OED*, and haven’t been updated since the second edition.

---

### [caliph | calif *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/26388) 1393

The title given in Muslim countries to the chief civil and religious ruler, as successor of Muhammad.

### [caliphate *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/26390) 1614

1. - a. The rank, dignity, or office of caliph.
   - b. The reign or term of office of a caliph
2. The dominion of a caliph.

### [sultan *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193879) 1555

1. - a. The sovereign or chief ruler of a Muslim country; *spec*. (*Hist*.) the sovereign of Turkey. Also formerly, a prince or king's son, a high officer.
   - b. Taken as a type of magnificence; also *attrib*.
   - c. Used with allusion to an Eastern ruler's harem; also *attrib*.
2. An absolute ruler; *gen*. a despot, tyrant.

### [sultanate *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193881) 1822

1. A state or country subject to a sultan; the territory ruled over by a sultan.
2. The office or power of a sultan.

### [sheikh *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177849) 1577

1. - a. The chief of an Arab family or tribe; the headman of an Arabian village; an Arab chief; †an Eastern governor, prince, king. Now also used among Arabs as a general title of respect.
   - b. (Chiefly in spelling *sheik*.) A type of a strong, romantic lover; a lady-killer.  [After *The Sheik*, a novel by E. M. Hull (1919), and its cinematic adaptation *The Sheikh*, 1921, starring Rudolph Valentino.]
2. - a. The head of a Muslim religious order or community; a great religious doctor or preacher; now *esp*. a saint having a local cultus.
   - b. ***Sheikh-ul-Islam*** (properly ***Sheikhu 'l Islam***)  : the supreme authority in matters relating to religion and sacred law; in Turkey, the mufti. Hence ***Sheikh-ul-Islamate***.
3. In India, one of a dissenting sect of Muslims; a general term for Hindu converts to Islam. (Usually *shekh*, *shaikh*.)

### [emir *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61191) 1625

1. A Saracen or Arab prince, or governor of a province; a military commander.
2. A title of honour borne by the descendants of the prophet Muhammad.

### [emirate *n.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61192) 1863

The jurisdiction or government of an emir.

Comment: @LewisCarroll Thank you.  Although a great many questions here in **ESL&U** could be justly closed as “general reference” if only the *OED* weren’t behind a paywall, alas it indeed is so. None of the free available dictionaries holds a candle to it, and so I find myself copying its entries into answers here quite a bit for people who have no subscription. Note that most universities and **many libraries *do* have a subscription**, which means that even today better research can often be done at the library than at home.

Comment: @tchrist: except some library subscriptions also allow remote access from home.

Comment: Thought it was **EL&U**, though it does sometimes look like it is 'ESL&U'.