# "Troublesome" vs. "annoying"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between "troublesome" and "annoying", especially when used to describe a person?

Comment: How do you understand the terms, from what you have learnt?

Comment: I see that my question is downvoted. Please tell me how I can improve it. Yesterday, I googled and found that these words are listed as synonyms of each other. I couldn't find a webpage that explained the difference, so I decided to ask here. Is this kind of questions not welcomed?

Comment: @netvope: You haven't told us what you _do_ know about the words. So, we are left to start from "square one". I would suggest that a question like this include definitions from a dictionary, as well as a few comments about why you're asking or why you're confused. It's not that these kinds of questions are not welcomed, it's that these kinds of questions should more closely follow a format such as is seen [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/what-is-the-difference-between-an-emperor-and-a-king).

Answer (score 1):

To call someone *troublesome* could be a neutral observation, perhaps the person is not bothering you yourself but maybe just generates trouble for someone else or himself

> A troublesome youth

for example, someone hanging about and getting into trouble

> He is so annoying

this person's activities actively irritates you.

Comment: Wait. Whatever happened to the dictionaries?

Comment: When i looked they more or less showed the words as synonyms

Comment: It's for the OP to do that, really.

Comment: Sure, but if the difference is not obvious from the dictionaries, we  can help, nop?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

A troublesome person actually causes trouble which is perceivable and perhaps even tangible and measurable. An annoying person irritates you and changes your mood. The difference between the two is in the nature of the outcome.

A troublesome person may cause annoyance but an annoying one need not necessarily cause trouble.

Comment: Is that not more or less exactly what I said?

Comment: @mplungjan I guess it is but I don't think "troublesome" is a neutral observation. I amended my answer slightly.

Comment: I said "could be" neutral as opposed to actively irritating