# When do we use "elder" "older" and "eldest"?

Tags: differences

I'd appreciate it if someone explained everything regarding those three adjectives. They confuse me.

Comment: Just a hint that might help you out, since this is your first question. Instead of saying something like, "I'd appreciate it if someone explained **everything** regarding X...", it would be better to (a) do some research on your own first, (b) explain what you've managed to learn in your question (in other words, *share your research*), and (c) ask something specific about where you are still confused. In the long run, those kinds of questions tend to garner more upvotes and less close votes. (I've written more [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/) if you're curious.)

Comment: Then what is this website used for?

Comment: It's not a free, interactive, on-line dictionary, if that's what you mean. [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63039) is my all-time favorite ELU question. Notice how the OP **didn't** ask: _What is the difference between a king and an emperor? I don't understand how these two words differ._ As it says on the [How to Ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page: _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking? Sharing your research helps. Tell us what you found. This demonstrates you’ve taken time to try to help yourself and saves us from obvious answers_

Answer (score 2):

Elder tends to be used for people and older for things. Oldest amd eldest are used when more than two things or people are being compared.

Comment: Can you give me examples for elder and older? I didn't quite understand that part.

Comment: He is the elder of two brothers: My car is older than his.

Answer (score 0):

An Elder is a term tentatively used as a noun, referring to someone of an aged person.

**Elder**

> *Noun*
>
> An aged person.

Older is used as an adjective and usually in the form of a comparison.

**Older**

> *Adj*
>
> a comparative of old.

Eldest is also used as an adjective, a superlative of old with elder as comparison.

**Eldest**

> *Adj*
>
> oldest; first-born; of greatest age:
>
> *eg*. *eldest brother, eldest sister*